# Monitors out of range on login

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, monitor

Ever since I installed my new graphics card (an RTX 2070 Super) I've been getting this weird problem with my Ubuntu 20.04 installation where 2 of my 3 screens stop working.  The firmware on the monitors themselves cite that the frequency is “out of range”.
I seem to be able to fix this temporarily by unplugging one of my monitors then re-plugging it, but it’s a pain to have to get down and round the back of the machine every time it starts since it sits under my desk. The problem comes back everytime I reboot my machine.

The weird thing about this problem is that it doesn’t show immediately on startup and only occurs when I log in to the OS – When I get to the password screen, all 3 monitors come up just fine, but then go out of range once I type my password and press enter. (In other words, when the desktop appears)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. Apparently my drivers weren't up to date like I thought. Updated through the software updater. Everything works now.